# Sonatype Nexus rest api upload by C#

Tags: c#, .net, nexus

I need to upload a artifact to Nexus by C# but cant understand how to interpret the "cUrl -F" parameter to tell the request name extension and to what repository should it go. Mb somebody can share a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what ended up working for me:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadArtifact(string artifactPath, string artifactName, string artifactId)
    {
        using var systemClient = new HttpClient
        {
            DefaultRequestHeaders =
            {
                Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                    Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{_nexusUsername}:{_nexusPassword}")))
            }
        };
        var client = _httpClient ?? new SystemHttpClient(systemClient);

        var data = _file.ReadAllBytes(artifactPath);
        using var content = new ByteArrayContent(data);

        var postUrl = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _settings.Value.NexusBaseUrl, artifactId, artifactName);
        return await client.PutAsync(new Uri(postUrl), content).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

The curl equivalent for this would look something like `curl -v -u admin:admin123 --upload-file pom.xml http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/org/foo/1.0/foo-1.0.pom`

Here is an example of something using the above method:

```
var response = await _nexusClient
    .UploadArtifact(zipFilePath, zipFileName, request.ApplicationName).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

And here is the full implementation of the class containing said method:

```
public interface INexusClient
{
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadArtifact(string artifactPath, string artifactName, string artifactId);
}

public sealed class NexusClient : INexusClient
{
    private readonly IFile _file;
    private readonly IHttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly string _nexusPassword;
    private readonly string _nexusUsername;
    private readonly IOptions<AppConfigurationSettings> _settings;

    public NexusClient(IOptions<AppConfigurationSettings> settings, IFile file, IHttpClient httpClient, IEnvironment environment)
    {
        _settings = settings ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(settings)} must not be null");
        _file = file;
        _httpClient = httpClient;

        if (environment == null) throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(environment)} must not be null");
        _nexusUsername = environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("nexusUsername");
        _nexusPassword = environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("nexusPassword");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_nexusUsername)) throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(_nexusUsername)} is not configured in this environment");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_nexusPassword)) throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(_nexusPassword)} is not configured in this environment");
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadArtifact(string artifactPath, string artifactName, string artifactId)
    {
        using var systemClient = new HttpClient
        {
            DefaultRequestHeaders =
            {
                Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                    Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{_nexusUsername}:{_nexusPassword}")))
            }
        };
        var client = _httpClient ?? new SystemHttpClient(systemClient);

        var data = _file.ReadAllBytes(artifactPath);
        using var content = new ByteArrayContent(data);

        var postUrl = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _settings.Value.NexusBaseUrl, artifactId, artifactName);
        return await client.PutAsync(new Uri(postUrl), content).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

*Note that IFile, IHttpClient, and IEnvironment are wrapper interfaces I used for the File, HttpClient and Environment classes respectively (to help with testing).